# Cloud authentication with AD synced users

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

We currently use an AAD instance with Federated user sign (via ADFS) and password sync enabled on AD Connect to sync the AD and AAD user accounts. The login on the portal redirects to the ADFS sts and correctly authenticates the directory users with the AD passwords.

Trying to achieve resource owner grant against the AAD instance for a client app registered on Azure using the token endpoint which results in a password error (despite using correct user password)

> error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password

```
POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/<domain>/oauth2/token
client_id={registered app id on azure}
&client_secret={secret}
&scope=code
&username={AD user}
&password={AD password}
&grant_type=password
resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
```

Try change the password on the Azure portal and the token authentication succeeds up until the time the password is synced again from AD (password write back is enabled); indicating the sync interfering with the password in a way so as to fail cloud authentication on AAD. Are there any considerations needed on the password sync for the AAD cloud authentication to be effective?

Comment: You need to URL-encode the form data, that's caused me that error in the past.

Comment: Thats in place but no luck. The client id and secret are on the basic authentication header(url encoded) and the body contents - user name and pwd send url encoded as well. As mentioned on the post the auth succeeds when the password is set on the Azure portal up until the time it is synced from the AD (MD4 hash)

Comment: Ahh should have seen that.

Answer (score 0):

> We currently use an AAD instance with Federated user sign (via ADFS) and password sync enabled on AD Connect to sync the AD and AAD user accounts. The login on the portal redirects to the ADFS sts and correctly authenticates the directory users with the AD passwords.

Resource Owner Password Grant flow does not work well for federated users.
It only really works for cloud-only users with no MFA and with a non-expired password.

Comment: Thanks for the update juunas. Is this a documented restriction?

Comment: Hi juunas, would you be able to confirm if this is documented somewhere? I am trying to use password grant for user accounts synced from on prem AD to AAD. It is only for couple of automation test accounts which will be used by coded tests to get token. I get the an invalid_grant error that says AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password. So I am trying to establish if this is at all possible. Thanks